# Análise Combinatória - Gerar n! arranjos

Tags: javascript, matemática

Preciso de um algoritmo que gere todos os arranjos possíveis para **n** elementos em **n** posições, ou seja, **n!** é a quantidade de arranjos possíveis, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
n = 3
3! = 6 arranjos

123
132
213
231
312
321
```

Estou tentando criá-lo em JavaScript, mas não está dando certo.

```
function partida(){
    var nc = 4;
    var nl = fatorial(nc);

    var jogada = new Array(nl);
    for (i = 0; i < nl; i++){
        jogada[i] = new Array(nc);
    }

    for (c = 0; c < nc; c++){
        var q = fatorial(nc - c)/(nc - c);
        for (l = 0; l < nl; l++){
            jogada[l][c] = Math.trunc(l/q) + c;
        }
    }

    textarea = document.getElementById('arranjos');
    for (l = 0; l < nl; l++){
        textarea.innerHTML += (jogada[l].toString()).replace(/,/g, "");
        textarea.innerHTML += '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha resposta foi inspirada nesse [post](http://marmsx.msxall.com/cursos/c16.html), caso quera maiores explicações.

Usei três funções para chegar na resposta.

```
function buld_char(valor){
    for (var i = 0; i < valor; i++) {
        lista.push(i+1);
    }
    permutacao_recursiva(lista,0);
}
```

Essa funão vai receber um valor, que no seu caso é `n` e vai montar um array com todos os valores de 1 até `n`. Ao final ele vai chamar a função `permutacao_recursiva()`;

```
function permutacao_recursiva(str,k){
    var i, len;
    len = str.length;

    if (k == len)
        console.log(str);
    else {
        for (i = k; i < len; i++) {
            str = troca_char(str, k, i);
            permutacao_recursiva(str, k + 1);
            str = troca_char(str, i, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Sempre que necessário esse função chamará uma terceira, que vai trocar os caracteres do array

```
function troca_char(str, p1, p2) {
    aux = str[p1];
    str[p1] = str[p2]
    str[p2] = aux;
    return str;
}
```

Tendo essas três funções basta declarar uma variável global

```
var lista = [];
```

e chamar a função `buld_char(3);` passando o valor de `n`

Comment: Não creio que a global seja necessária. Pelo que percebi, ela poderia muito bem ser local de `build_char`